# error: could not find or load main class java after updating -Xss Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have tried all the recommended solutions for this but I can't manage to fix it. After going to Run / Run configurations / Arguments and writing in the VM Arguments section  "java -Xss2048m" I get the error:

```
error: could not find or load main class java
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `java`. The VM Arguments section only contains the arguments and not the Java command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with -Xss.  I didn't see it in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22289_01/html/821-1274/configuring-the-default-jvm-and-java-arguments.html#scrolltoc) for JVM options by Oracle.

If you're trying to set initial and max heap sizes, shouldn't that be -Xms or -Xmx?

Do you have a 64 bit operating system and 64 bit JVM?  If not, you won't be able to get more than 1.7 GB heap.